# How to use composite index in range query in mysql

Tags: mysql, index, performance, query-performance

I have a table：

```
create table test (
   field1 bigint,
   field2 bigint
);

alter table test 
add index field1_field2 (field1, field2)
```

Here is a sql :

```
select * 
from test 
    force index(field1_field2)
where field1 > 100 
  and field2 = 2 
limit 200 ;
```

and it doesn't run very well. I Explained it and found that only `field1` condition used by index query, `field2` condition was ignored.

I want know why, and I need a perfect answer.

There are lots of data with `field1 > 100` and lots of data with `field2 = 2`.

Comment: Edit your question with the proper `create table` statements, plus an `explain` of the query

Comment: A `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` can lead to getting random rows.

Answer (score 13):

You need a composite index on the columns (they are not fields!), but in **reverse order**, on `(field2, field1)` for this query.

When a condition has equality checks (`=`) and range/inequality checks (`>`, `>=`, `<`, `<=`, `IN`), then the columns involved in the equality checks should be first in the index and the inequality columns afterwards.

```
alter table test 
    add index ix_field2_field1 
    (field2, field1) ;
```

Additional notes:

- A query with `LIMIT` and without `ORDER BY` will yield indeterminate results. Always use `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT` unless you don't care if you get different results per execution:

  ```
  select * 
  from test  
                            -- no need to force anything
  where field2 = 2          -- the order here doesn't matter
    and field1 > 100        -- but is useful for developers
  order by field2, field1
  limit 200 ;
  ```
- Really, choose some proper names for the columns, not "field1", "field2", etc.
- Your table does not have a `PRIMARY KEY` defined. This is not good both from a theoretical and a practical point of view. Assuming that the table uses the InnoDB engine, then by not defining a primary key, InnoDB adds a  6-byte hidden column that is used as the clustered index. This also means that all your indexes have this 6-byte column attached, making them wider. I suggest you have a - preferably narrow - `PRIMARY KEY` in all tables.

Comment: [_Cookbook_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/) that discusses tips like this.